# Proof for $\frac{b}{h}=\frac{c(c-1)}{k(k-1)}$, a combinatorial identity

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, combinatory-logic

Imagine we have $b$ teachers and $c$ students in a school such that

1. each teacher teaches $k$ students,
2. every two students have $h$ similar teachers.

I'd like to prove that
$$\frac{b}{h}\:=\:\frac{c(c-1)}{k(k-1)}\,.$$
I thought about it for a little bit but weirdly enough, I have no insights on this.
A hint, an answer, or both would be appreciated.

Comment: A good first step for this type of problem is to plug in real numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adress to each teacher a pair of students he/she teaches (so he adresses ${k\choose 2}$ pairs) and vice versa, to each pair of students a teacher they are listening (so they adresses $h$ teachers).

Then by double counting we have: $$b\cdot {k\choose 2} = {c\choose 2}\cdot h$$

Can you finsih now?

Comment: This is beatiful logic!(+1)

Comment: I can take it from here . But yet I don’t understand your logic properly. Can your please take the time to explain more?

Comment: Make a bipartite graph where one partition has teacher and other pairs of students and make a connection between them if a teacher teaches a pair.

Comment: Brilliant.thank you.